# Gitlab stop CI if Dockerized R CMD check return errors

Tags: r, docker, gitlab-ci, testthat

How can I make my CI pipeline fail if the test stage return errors ?

Here is my test stage :

```
Test:
  stage: Test
  script:
    - docker build -t r-docker-ci-test -f test.Dockerfile .
    - docker run r-docker-ci-test
```

Here is my test.Dockerfile :

```
FROM r-base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('devtools', 'testthat'), dependencies=TRUE)"

COPY . /usr/local/src/test
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/test

CMD R -e "devtools::check()"
```

And here is the output :

```
R CMD check results
1 error  | 2 warnings | 2 notes
.
.
.
Job succeeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitLab and Docker are working as expected, it's more of a question about the exit code of the command that you are running, your problem is that it's 0 even when it reports test errors.

You can tackle this at the `Dockerfile` `CMD` stanza and change the test running R command to to `R CMD check` as suggested [here](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/515).

Or you can tackle in the GitLab pipeline spec and `grep` your way to a non-zero exit code like this:

```
Test:
  stage: Test
  script:
    - docker build -t r-docker-ci-test -f test.Dockerfile .
    - docker run r-docker-ci-test | | grep '^0\serror' > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to make it run using a docker runner for gitlab, pulling the r-base image and using "R CMD check ." !